# check different prices in different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

let's say i have 3 tables:

1. ITEMS table (all the info about item)
2. ITEM_Pricing (multiple prices for the same item)
3. Special Prices (IF we have special price for certain items or promotions)

I want to build a query to check for the price if exists in **special prices** table display it, if not take what's in **Item_Pricing** table. in other words i want to check if the item exists in special prices table first with price if not go and check in item_pricing table.

this is what i tried, of course not giving the correct answer

```
select T0.itemcode,T0.ItemName,T0.OnHand,T1.price, T2.Price as Special
from ITEM T0, PRICES T1, S_PRICES T2
where 
    T0.ItemCode=T1.ItemCode
and T0.ItemCode=T2.ItemCode
```

looks easy but i can't figure out how to do it?? I'm using sql server 2008 R2

any help will be appreciated

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple rule:  just say "No" to commas in `from` clauses.  It is time for you to learn explicit `join` syntax rather than the implicit syntax where the conditions go in the `where` clause.

If you wrote the query using explicit joins, then the answer would simply be along the lines of "You need to use a `left outer join`".  And guess what?  That is not easily done when the conditions are in the `where` clause.

```
select i.itemcode, i.ItemName, i.OnHand, p.price, sp.Price as Special,
       coalesce(sp.Price, p.price) as ThePriceIWant
from ITEM i left outer join
     PRICES p
     on p.itemCode = i.ItemCode left outer join
     S_PRICES sp
     on sp.itemCode = i.ItemCode;
```

Note the logic using `coalesce()` to get the price you want.  And the use of table abbreviations as table aliases -- they make the query much easier to follow.

Answer (score 2):

Something along these lines

```
select      T0.itemcode,T0.ItemName,T0.OnHand,
        IsNull(T2.Price, T1.Price) As Price
from        ITEM as T0
left join   PRICES as T1
        on  T1.ItemCode = T0.ItemCode
left join   S_PRICES as T2
        on  T2.ItemCode = T0.ItemCode
```

This assumes there is zero or one SpecialPrice and zero or one Price